# OS -> Restart Fails to find NVME Boot Disk

Tags: boot, bios, nvme

This one has only recently started happening and has me completely stumped.

**Flow Fails**

Running OS -> Start -> Power -> Restart

The machine shuts down the OS without power cycling but then the BIOS pauses with a message reported by my Asus X299 Deluxe as "Detect HDD".

**Flow Works**

Running OS -> Start -> Power -> Shut down (Power cycle) -> Boot from Power Button.  BOOM. Everything is fine an' dandy.

I'm not even entirely sure where to start investigating as it's such an odd problem. I've just noticed I'm a few versions behind at the moment but this is a new problem to this machine running this BIOS version. So it's not like this BIOS version introduced the issue.

The OS drive is a Samsung 960 Pro 512Gb NVMe.

Sleep and Hibernate are already disabled.

I flashed the motherboard BIOS to the latest version 3201. I've also checked to make sure all my drives are running their latest firmware using Samsung Magician. All are running the latest.

There is an interesting discussion [here](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/asus-x99-aii-motherboard-doesnt-detect-m-2-samsung-960-evo.2938991/) describing similar issues on ASUS x99 boards and Samsung SSDs. But no real solution that has worked for me.

Comment: I would strongly consider upgrading the firmware

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I have sleep and hibernation all disabled so that a shutdown really is a shutdown. I'm going to do the BIOS updates tomorrow as one of the versions includes a microcode update so I don't want to skip that anyway. I'll see what the system is doing after that.

Comment: @Ramhound agreed. I'm leaning this way too.

Comment: @Ramhound I just flashed the BIOS. Rebooted and all is well. Did a restart and that also worked flawlessly.

Comment: Spoke too soon. Just did another restart and it had the same problem described in the OP.

Comment: What usb device is generating that error?

Comment: I've fixed that issue now, it was a WiFi driver.